# Remove File From PR

Tags: git

I need to remove one file from PR that I have changed in few commits and pushed in my feature branch. I am trying the following :

In my PR branch in run the command :

```
git checkout origin/develop -- path/to/my/file
```

when I type `git status` ,  no change is shown. Hence, not able to commit/push

Next, when i compare my local file in feature branch with copy present in develop branch (using beyond compare) -> content are same/no diff

**But when I see my PR, I still can see changes in that file and that file present in PR.**

It seems changes are not getting push/commit.

Any solution to solve this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

That's not a direct answer, but I would try to simply restore the file from upstream and commit it in the PR branch, i.e.:

```
git show origin/master:path > path
git add path
git commit -m"restore [file]"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing the following:

1. Delete the file from filesystem
2. `git add your-file` or `git add .`
3. `git commit -m "commit message"`
4. `git push`